# SequenceFile.Writer leads to NullPointerException

Tags: nullpointerexception, mahout, sequencefile

Hi I am trying to create a simple sequencefile with mahout libraries using the bellow code. While running the code I am getting NullPointerException after creating a empty file,

```
public class SequenceFileWriter {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        SequenceFile.Writer sfw = new SequenceFile.Writer(fs, conf, new Path("/tmp/test.txt"), Text.class, Text.class);
        Text A = new Text();
        Text B = new Text();
        for (int x = 0; x < 1000; x++) {
            A.set("a" + x);
            B.set("b" + x);
            sfw.append(A, B);
        }
        org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.closeStream(sfw);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1010)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:445)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:418)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:650)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:739)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:722)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:633)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.setPermission(FilterFileSystem.java:467)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:424)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:906)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:887)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:784)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:773)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Writer.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1103)
    at com.jarvis.trial.SequenceFileWriter.main(SequenceFileWriter.java:15)
```

Could anyone please help me on this to sort the issue?